# append text to file using shell from php

Tags: bash, shell, ubuntu, quoting

I trying to append passed text as parameter to file using shell script
this is the code of shell

```
 echo $1>>/etc/freeradius/mods-enabled/ldap
```

this shell will get the text to add it to  the file ldap in /etc/freeradius/mods-enabled  path , I call this shell in this format

```
# sh /etc/append.sh hello how are you man
```

but in this example the shell only get first word 'hello' and append it to file .how can I tell shell that all words are same variable and should insert to file

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the shell you're using.
In `bash` the this script should work:

```
#!/bin/bash  
echo "${@:1}">>/etc/freeradius/mods-enabled/ldap
```

***Edit:*** As DTSCode pointed out in comments the `:1` part in the script is redundant so this would be more correct:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "$@" >> /etc/freeradius/mods-enabled/ldap
```

Then give the permissions to execute the file and call

```
/etc/append.sh hello how are you man
```

Or without execute permission call

```
bash /etc/append.sh hello how are you man
```

Comment: @ should really be quoted: `"${@:1}"`. Although, the :1 is redundant here, so it should really just be `echo "$@" >> /etc/...`. (you could probably actually get away with just `"$*"` instead, since you're just printing the values)

Comment: @DTSCode Good points! I wonder how I missed the quotes (probably because I ran a test in my laptop and it worked without quotes as well). Will edit the answer.